# Xcode storyboard UIWebView won't load

Tags: ios, xcode, uiwebview, storyboard, viewcontroller

So all I want to do is create an App that has two pages: one with a button that opens up a `UIWebView` in the second. It seems simple enough, yet I have spent the past two days trying to figure it out.

I create the object and put in the code for the link and ctr - drag the web-view to the `controlview.h` but nothing will work.

Does anyone know a tutorial or can explain this to me? I have been searching the web for the pat two days and have gotten nowhere. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Each "page" should be a separate view controller. You open the storyboard editor, drag a view controller to it, drag a web view to your new view controller, then drag a segue from the appropriate control on the first page to the second page.

You will also need to create a UIViewController class for the second page, and set the controller's identity in the storyboard editor.  (Select the second controller, type command-option-3, enter the view controller's class name in the "Custom Class" section.)

In the second view controller you will need some code to make the webview do something, obviously, so you probably will want to create an outlet for the webview.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should start out with this general guide on [View Controllers](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html). You'll learn how to use View Controllers and how to present Modal View Controllers.

After that you go on with the documentation about [UIWebView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

If you do a quick search for UIWebView you'll find tons of tutorials, but basics are important :)

Answer (score -1):

CONTROL+DRAG does not work on storyboard. When I click view and drag to UIWebView, it opens a black popup but I cannot see my web value. I just see "view".

It does not work on storyboard either. I tried it on xib and it works with that.

Comment: -1 : This is not the problem he is facing. You say how to link a component to its Outlet, or whatever, but he has a Class-linking issue.